Umount before running service in systemd
I have a systemd unit service script which initiates borgmatic to do the procedure of backing up.
I would like to umount potentially virtually mounted archives of borgmatic in order to avoid error.
I've added a row
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/umount /mnt/backup || true

to this borgmatic.service unit script
[Unit]
Description=borgmatic backup
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
ConditionACPower=true

[Service]
Type=oneshot

LockPersonality=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=no
NoNewPrivileges=yes
PrivateDevices=yes
PrivateTmp=yes
ProtectClock=yes
ProtectControlGroups=yes
ProtectHostname=yes
ProtectKernelLogs=yes
ProtectKernelModules=yes
ProtectKernelTunables=yes
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6 AF_NETLINK
RestrictNamespaces=yes
RestrictRealtime=yes
RestrictSUIDSGID=yes
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallFilter=@system-service
SystemCallErrorNumber=EPERM
ProtectSystem=full

ReadWritePaths=/backup

#CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH CAP_NET_RAW

Nice=19
CPUSchedulingPolicy=batch
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
IOSchedulingPriority=7
IOWeight=100

Restart=no
LogRateLimitIntervalSec=0

ExecStartPre=sleep 1m
ExecStartPre=sudo /usr/bin/umount /mnt/backup || true
ExecStart=systemd-inhibit --who="borgmatic" --why="Prevent interrupting scheduled backup" borgmatic --syslog-verbosity 1

However, when the timer starts it I am getting errors that the umount should be run on behalf of sudo user. I've added sudo to the command, so it is now:
ExecStartPre=sudo /usr/bin/umount /mnt/backup || sudo true

That didn't help much:
Apr 27 06:07:01 myhostnamt.tld sudo[617036]:     root : PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/umount /mnt/backup || sudo true
Apr 27 06:07:01 myhostnamt.tld sudo[617036]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
Apr 27 06:07:01 myhostnamt.tld sudo[617039]: umount: /mnt/backup: must be superuser to unmount.
Apr 27 06:07:01 myhostnamt.tld sudo[617039]: umount: ||: must be superuser to unmount.
Apr 27 06:07:01 myhostnamt.tld sudo[617039]: umount: sudo: must be superuser to unmount.
Apr 27 06:07:01 myhostnamt.tld sudo[617039]: umount: true: must be superuser to unmount.

What may be wrong?

I don't think you can use shell constructs (like ||) in a Exec= (unless you wrap them in an actual shell, ex. sh -c ' ... || ... ') so ||, sudo, and true are all getting passed as arguments to /usr/bin/umount. In any case, you shouldn't need sudo if this is being run as a systemd system service (not as a user service). Can you please back up and show us the complete verbatim error that led you to believe that "the umount should be run on behalf of sudo user"?
